# How to save webpages and open it after clicking?

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiAVy.png)

Attached is screenshot for my view controller. When users search on internet, how do I realize these functions?

1. save current web page ( maybe go to another view controller after clicking "save")
2. my idea is to save on a table view, with a brief title
3. after clicking the title, shows contents of the whole page saved.
4. if users reply emails on some website with attachments, they can also save the attachments (word, pdf,etc) in the app.

I initialized the web view with google. The problem is the page to be saved can be any NSURL, I have no idea how to do that.

Or you can advise some way totally different, as long as I can realize these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference you should include some code... but anyway, I would just set the NSURL as a string of each webpage in NSUserDefaults then call the main applications open URL method.

Like...

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setObject("YourURL" forKey: "URLKey")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.synchronize()
```

Then retrieve it like...

```
if let urlString = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.objectForKey("URLKey") {

let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

UIApplicationSharedApplication.openURL(url)

}
```

I wrote this code off the top of my head so it might need some tweaking but I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have got the idea. Just one question so far, users can visit and save any website, so I don't know how to set the "YourURL" in your example. Can you explain more?

Comment: ok Echizzle, I found the way to grab the current url:  currentURL = currentWebView.request.URL.absoluteString.  I think this is the correct way to get any current url?

Comment: That should work, and cool, glad I could help, don't forget to upvote/mark the answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to save many webpages, you should *not* use `NSUserDefaults` to achieve it. You should use something called `CoreData`. This is because `NSUserDefaults` can only save one url at a time. If you want to save another, you need another key to do so.

Here is basically what you need to do. You create a new Core Data Model file (.xcdatamodeld). Add an entity called `SavedUrls`. Add a property to that entity called `urlString`. Then generate a `NSManagedObject` subclass.

To save data, get the managed object context from the App Delegate. Create a new instance of `SavedUrls` using the inherited initializer. And change the property to the url to be saved. Then just call `save` on the context.

To get data back, get the managed object context and create an `NSFetchRequest` to fetch from the database.

Learn more here:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial

Comment: Hi Sweeper, thanks for the tips regarding coredata. I have used coredata with simple functions before, so this time I can expand my knowledge about  coredata.                                                                                                            I have set up Firebase in my app. So if more and more users register in the future, which is better to use in this case, Firebase or Coredata?

Comment: If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark/tick thingy. @Mike

Comment: Hi Sweeper, can you explain more about when yo use Coredata and when to use third party server provider like Firebase? Which is better choice in this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: @Mike If you want to save the data to a server, then use something like Firebase. If you want to save the data on the users' phones, use Core Data. In your scenario, IMO it's better to save the URLs on the device.

Comment: Hi Sweeper, now I got it. I already set up Firebase and finished Facebook login. It won't hurt if I use Firebase, right? Or can I use both of them in the app?    I hope I can mark both answers because they are all helpful, just the first one gave me a start and your answer let me know more about Coredata. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mike Yes it won't hurt.

Comment: Yes this is true but you can save an array to NSUserDefaults, I should have worked that into my code. If you're not storing a lot it's much easier to set up than Core Data although both options are perfectly viable.